# oracle pl sql function having errors

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a function that returns the number of rows in a table called Rating with a where clause.Where am i going wrong before the declare statement and the end statement?

```
 create or replace
FUNCTION get_movies(user IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*)
INTO cnt 
FROM rating
where userid= user;
RETURN cnt;
END;
```

I will appreciate help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have the `DECLARE` keyword. You only need that for an anonymous block (or a sub-block).

```
create or replace
FUNCTION get_movies(p_userid IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ...
```

`user` is a reserved word so I'd suggest not using that as your parameter name. In the `where` clause I'm not sure if it will use your parameter value, or the name of the user executing the function; which would error as that string value couldn't be implicitly converted to a number.

Comment: Thanks Alex,i diddnt notice that.Thank you.